# Pulled a Joomla site from live to local, getting 404 - Component not found

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Joomla is up to date. I downloaded a live site to set up locally. I am completely new to Joomla! but i have a lot of experience in wordpress. So i changed the redirect links so the local site would stop redirecting to live. However now i'm getting:

You may not be able to visit this page because of:

an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
a mistyped address
you have no access to this page
The requested resource was not found.
An error has occurred while processing your request.
Please try one of the following pages:

Home Page
If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below..

I have tried turning SEF off, is there any other solutions to fix this?

Cheers

Edit:

Stack trace:
Component not found.

Call stack

## Function    Location

1   JApplicationCms->execute()  C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\celtic\index.php:53

2   JApplicationSite->doExecute()   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\celtic\libraries\cms\application\cms.php:261

3   JApplicationSite->dispatch()    C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\celtic\libraries\cms\application\site.php:229

4   JComponentHelper::renderComponent() C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\celtic\libraries\cms\application\site.php:190

Comment: When you say you "pulled it" do you mean you ftped the files and then created a database and imported the back up of the data base? Or did you use one of the extensions that manages that?   If you did it yourself, did you make sure to change all relevant variables in the configuration file?

Comment: Did you use Akeeba to export and import your site. Also did you rename your .htaccess file and checked it? Sometimes if you modify the .htaccess default file you may face problem when you take your site to some other server.